# Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $G ⊆ X$. and prove the following

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $G ⊆ X$. Show the following:

(i) If $x ∈ G$ then $x$ is either a limit or isolated point of $G$.

(ii) If $G$ is finite then $G$ is closed.

(iii) The set of limit points of $G$ is closed.

I'm not quite certain how to approach these problems even though I've tried using the definitions of the different points. Thank you for your help!

Comment: (i) does not seem right. A correct statement would be that $x\in X$ may only be an element of $G$, a limit point of $G$ or a point in the exterior of $G$.

Comment: I think that's what the question is trying to ask but phrased it oddly.

Comment: ... *or* the hypothesis was supposed to be $x\in G$.

Comment: Yes :( I entered the question wrongly. I'm an idiot. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i), if $x$ is not a limit point of $G$ that means there is some open $x\in U$ such that $U\cap G =\lbrace x\rbrace$.For (ii), a point in a metric space is a closed set.  A finite set is an union of (its) points and since closed sets are closed under finite unions, a finite set is closed. For (iii),  suppose that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and each $x_n$ is a limit point. Take any open set $x\in U$ so that there is some $p$ such that for all $m\geq p$, $x_m\in U$. Now $U$ is also an open set containing limit points (elements from $x_n$) and thus it follows that $x$ is a limit point itself and hence, the set of limit points is closed. Note we could assume $x_n\neq x$ without loss of generality.

Maybe (iii) a bit more clearly : Let $L$ be the set of limit points of $G$. We want to prove that $L=\overline{L}$. So take $x\in\overline{L}$ so that for every open $x\in U$ one has that $U\cap L\neq \emptyset$. Let $y\in U\cap L$ and take open $V$ such that $y\in V\subseteq U$ and such that $x\notin U$, which is possible since $X$ is Hausdorff. Now, $V\cap G\setminus \lbrace y\rbrace \neq \emptyset$ and thus, $x\in L$.

Comment: That was neat. Danke Schön!

Comment: do you mind explaining (i) in a bit more depth? I'm a little confused. (ii) and (iii) are crystal clear.

Comment: There are two possibilities for $x\in G$ (one statement is the negation of the other) : either each open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ is such that $U\cap G\setminus\lbrace x\rbrace \neq \emptyset$ or there is an open $U$ containing $x$ such that that intersection is empty. By definition, in the first case $x$ is a limit point of $G$ and in the second case, $x$ is an isolated point of $G$ (as $U\cap G =\lbrace x\rbrace$)